# Hypergeometric function ratios: $\frac{_{2}F_{1}(a+1,b;c;x)}{_{2}F_{1}(a,b;c;x)}$?

Tags: hypergeometric-function

I need a numerically stable way to compute the following ratio:

$$\frac{_{2}F_{1}(a+1,b;c;x)}{_{2}F_{1}(a,b;c;x)},$$

All the parameters are real numbers, with $a< 0$,$\ $ $b,c > 0$ and $0<x<1$.

Right now I am using GSL's implementation of the hypergeometric function, but I keep getting underflows/overflows.

Is there a simplification that I can use?

**Update:** Following @Leiucippus comment, is there a continued fraction expansion for $\frac{_{2}F_{1}(a+1,b;c;x)}{_{2}F_{1}(a,b;c;x)}$ and/or $\frac{_{2}F_{1}(a+2,b;c;x)}{_{2}F_{1}(a,b;c;x)}$? Hopefully one that converges quickly so it is numerically useful.

Comment: Gauss has a method for a continued fraction method http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_continued_fraction

Comment: @Leucippus I don't see how that helps. There you have equations relating $_2F_1(a+1,b;c+1;x)$ to $_2F_1(a,b;c;x)$, but not $_2F_1(a+1,b;c;x)$ to $_2F_1(a,b;c;x)$. How can I use that?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little late to the game but you can work with the [contigious relations](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1110256X1200020X) of the hypergeometric function to get the ratio into a more useful form for using continued fraction expansions. Using the notation of the linked paper we may write
$$
\begin{aligned}
F\left({a+1,b\atop c};z\right)%
&=\mathcal A_1 F\left({a,b\atop c};z\right)\\
&=\left(\mathcal I+\frac{bz}{c}\mathcal A_1\mathcal A_2\mathcal A_3\right) F\left({a,b\atop c};z\right).
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{F(a+1,b;c;z)}{F(a,b;c;z)}%
&=1+\frac{b z}{c}\frac{F(a+1,b+1;c+1;z)}{F(a,b;c;z)}\\
&=1+bz\frac{\mathbf F(a+1,b+1;c+1;z)}{\mathbf F(a,b;c;z)}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Then, [DLMF $\S 15.7$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.7) provides continued fraction expansions for the remaining ratio of hypergeometric functions for certain values of $z$. If this does not help you can further work with these contiguous relations to turn your expression into a ratio of hypergeometric functions that will match one of the continued fraction expansions.